# constructor of one class, casting for other.. what function will be called?

Tags: c++, casting, constructor

I have 2 classes, A and B, both have function g().

If I do :

```
(A*) a = (A*) new B;

a->g();
```

function g() of what class will be called ?

Comment: is `A` base of `B`? Is `g()` declared as virtual?

Comment: Why don't you just try it? put in the function of A a `printf("In A");` and in the function of B a `printf("In B");`. Compile, Execute and you will see.. :-)

Comment: @sternze - it could be UB and a test may be useless, and even harmful/misleading (especially as this is a c-style cast).

Comment: Would this not create an ambiguous result?

Comment: Basically, for this case, if the cast is _absolutely neccesary_ (to compile without errors), then you have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

If `A` declares the function to be virtual, and `B` inherits from `A` and overrides it, then `B::g` will be called.

If it's not virtual, or not overridden, then `A::g` will be called.

If `B` doesn't inherit from `A`, then the behaviour is undefined and anything could happen. You can avoid this error by using an implicit conversion, which the compiler will only allow if it's known to be valid, rather than the most dangerous type of cast, which will allow most pointer conversions whether they make sense or not.